# Is there a way to load a shortcode onclick event in javascript?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to use a shortcode for a Masonry Gallery. I want to create 4 tabs. Once you click on tab #2, it should display a div and hide the others (which are already hidden by css). But when I click on tab #2, 3, or 4, the masonry gallery doesn't display until you click on a sort menu associated with the gallery. So Is there a way to add a simple function to this code so that I can load the shortcode upon click?

All I am doing with the tabs in the html is calling the function on click event. 
Sample Html:  onClick="displayClothing()"

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function displayClothing() {
document.getElementById("tab-1").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("tab-2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("tab-3").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("tab-4").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("grid-fx1") {
    //Load gridfx id #1 shortcode  by calling script
 }
}
function displayPocket() {
document.getElementById("tab-2").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("tab-1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("tab-3").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("tab-4").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("grid-fx2") {
    //Load gridfx id #2 shortcode  by calling script
 }
}
function display287art() {
document.getElementById("tab-3").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("tab-1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("tab-2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("tab-4").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("grid-fx3") {
    //Load gridfx id #3 shortcode by calling script
 }
}   
function display350art() {
document.getElementById("tab-4").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("tab-1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("tab-2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("tab-3").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("grid-fx4") {
    //Load gridfx id #4 shortcode by calling script
 }
}
```

AND WHAT I WANT TO DO IS LOAD THIS BUT THERE WILL BE 4 DIFFERENT SHORTCODES IN DIFFERENT DIV'S:

```
 [gridfx theme="light" posttypes="product"  show_title="1" columns=6 integrate="woocommerce" item_custom_field="woocommerce" single_item_custom_field"=woocommerce" excerpt_over_image="30" sortmenu="1"]
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What is happening is that the first tab content gallery shows up. But the other 3 shortcodes aren't being loaded all the way. When I click a tab, the second gallery is suppose to show up but is blank. But when I click on a sort dropdown that is part of the gallery, then the images in the gallery loads. I just need them all to load no matter what.

Comment: I edited the question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with JavaScript or jQuery. WordPress shortcodes are rendered on the server side. If your tabs are not show what you expected, you'd better check the PHP code (woocommerce plugin or any woo theme you're using).

Comment: And by the way, shortcodes are rendered in the post formatting phase. That means, insert shortcodes from your WP post editor. Otherwise they won't work.

Comment: I understand that. But I think it is more of an ajax issue. I asked the plugin creator if you can have multiple shortcodes on one page and they said yes. But something happens when I tell the css to display none on the other 3. When I click a tab, the gallery doesn't show the images.

Comment: It will show the images once I use the dropdown menu "Sort by High/Low".

Comment: Maybe its more of a CSS issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**functions.php**

```
function its_my_shortcode(){
echo "HI";
}

add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'its_my_shortcode');

function ajax_r(){
do_shortcode('[myshortcode]');
}

add_action ( 'wp_ajax_myshortcode', 'ajax_r' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myshortcode', 'ajax_r' );

function make_on_init(){ 
echo "<script>var ajaxhandle = '".admin_url('admin-ajax.php')."';</script>"; 
} 

add_action('wp_head', 'make_on_init');
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#element").click(function(){
var params = {
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxhandle,         
            data:  {
                "action" : 'myshortcode'                                
            },
            //dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 30000,
            beforeSend : function(){  

            },
            success: function( res ) {  
                $("#tabcontent").html(res);
            }

        };
        $.ajax( params ); 
});
});
```

This will show "HI" in the `#tabcontent` from `myshortcode` short code.

Comment: If I have 4 different tabs, how would I duplicate this to create additional tabs and where does it know to stick the shortcode at? Example: The tab id I am clicking on is #tab-1 and I want it to show #tabcontent-1 with shortcode inside the div. Then If I click on #tab-2, then show #tabcontent-2 and the shortcode inside. Also, do I replace the 'myshortcode' in the paremeters with the shortcode for the gridfx?

Comment: I user `$("#element")` instead add click event to your `$("#tag-1")`, `$("#tag-1")` and so and add various function add ajax action. Whatever you give wp_ajax_`myshortcode` here will be user here as "action" : `'myshortcode' `.

Comment: Ok So how would I tell it to display the shortcode in #tabcontent-2 if #tab-2 is clicked?

Comment: `$("#tab-2").click(function(){`
var params = {
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxhandle,         
            data:  {
                "action" : 'myshortcode'                                
            },
            //dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 30000,
            beforeSend : function(){  

            },
            success: function( res ) {  
                `$("#tabcontent").html(res);`
            }

        };
        $.ajax( params ); 
});

Comment: Change highlighted lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104768/discussion-between-hemnath-mouli-and-user2593040).